# Distinguish Stripe refunds invoices

Tags: stripe-payments

I am listening to these two events in Stripe `invoice.payment_succeeded` and `payment_intent.succeeded` to check whenever a user pays for a subscription and thus I grant him the right to access my website's content.However, soon my client will start to do refunds for his website users so I am afraid that my code will be affected if these 2 events are fired in the case of a refund as well. Is there a way to distinguish between a refund invoice (that will hold a certain amount) and another normal invoice that is generated upon subscription ? PS: in payment intent succeeded I have checked for  this condition`if(isset($response->data->object->payment_intent))`  before granting the role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those events will be fired in the case of a refund.

There is also no concept of a "refund invoice". Instead you'd listen for the `charge.refund.updated` event for refunds: https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-charge.refund.updated